# Informed sender in Lazaridou et al. (2017) 's guessing game

Tags: keras, cnn, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement the informed sender from *Multi-Agent Cooperation and the Emergence of (Natural) Language* ([Lazaridou et al., 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.07182)). However I'm confused about the tensor shape in the forward pass.

In the paper the network is described as following:

> The informed sender also first embeds the images into a “game-specific” space. It then applies
>   1-D convolutions (“filters”) on the image embeddings by treating them as different channels. The
>   informed sender uses convolutions with kernel size 2×1 applied dimension-by-dimension to the
>   two image embeddings (in *Figure 1*, there are 4 such filters). This is followed by the sigmoid
>   nonlinearity. The resulting feature maps are combined through another filter (kernel size f×1, where
>   f is the number of filters on the image embeddings), to produce scores for the vocabulary symbols.

Figure 1:

[image: Network graph]

So I assume the data should pass through the net as following:

1. The input is 2 feature vectors of shape `(None, n_features)`
2. They each get embedded via a Dense layer, output shape `(None, n_game_features)`
3. Here I'm not sure but I assume that in Keras, before passing them to the convolution layer, I need to stack those two vectors, forming `(None, 2, n_game_features)`
4. The vector passes through `Conv1D(n_feature_filters, kernel_size=2, activation="sigmoid", data_format="channels_first")`, outputting `(None, n_feature_filters, n_game_features)`.
5. This passes through the vocabulary filter `Conv1D(1, kernel_size=n_feature_filters, data_format="channels_first")`, outputting `(None, 1, n_game_features)`.

However, according to the paper, the output vector should be of length `vocabulary_size` which is independent on all the other parameters. **Should I assume an additional Dense layer on the output**, even though it was not mentioned in the paper? Or was there a mistake in my interpretation of the model specification?